# Solve $6\cos^2(x) - 8\cos(x)\sin(x) + 1 = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

How would you solve this equation for answers between $0$ and $360$ degrees?
$6\cos^2(x) - 8\cos(x)\sin(x) + 1 = 0$

(edit)I have tried the following:

- $10\cos(x)(6/10\cos(x) - 8/10\sin(x)) + 1 = 0 $
- $10\cos(x)(\cos(y)\cos(x) - \sin(y)(\sin(x)) + 1 = 0$
- $10\cos(x)\cos(x+y) + 1 = 0$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Ill edit in what i tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:*

Recall that $2\cos^2 x=1+\cos (2x)$ and $2\cos x\sin x=\sin (2x).$

Answer (score 2):

I like the following way.

We have $$6\cos^2x-8\sin{x}\cos{x}+\sin^2x+\cos^2x=0$$ or
$$\sin^2x-8\sin{x}\cos{x}+7\cos^2x=0$$ or
$$(\sin{x}-\cos{x})(\sin{x}-7\cos{x})=0.$$
1. $\sin{x}=\cos{x}.$

$$x=45^{\circ}+180^{\circ}k$$ where $k\in\{0,1\}$.

2. $\sin{x}=7\cos{x},$ which gives
   $$x=\arctan7+180^{\circ}k,$$ where $k\in\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

hint: Use the so-called Weierstrass substition:
$$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As $\sin x\cos x\ne0$

Divide both sides by $\cos^2x$ to form a quadratic equation in $\tan x$

Or divide both sides by $\sin^2x$

Or use double angle formula for  $\sin2x,\cos2x$